# Receiving intermittent warning - "Unable to delete temporary files"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We've noticed that we're getting the following warnings when running some of our CDF jobs.

Is this anything to be concerned about?

> 2015-04-27T22:42:16.442Z: S09: (49e39a5770173e26): Unable to delete
>   temporary files
>   gs://[removed]/cdf-mapped/dax-tmp-2015-04-27_15_36_45-15805476788472573847-S09-1-81f2ef2477e4a2bc/NetworkActiveViews_232503_20150427@DAX.csv$
>   Causes: (49e39a5770173187): Unable to delete directory:
>   gs://[removed]/cdf-mapped/dax-tmp-2015-04-27_15_36_45-15805476788472573847-S09-1-81f2ef2477e4a2bc.

Comment: It is likely not something that will cause your job to fail, but it's similar to a service bug we're investigating. Do you see any files actually left over in gs://[removed]/cdf-mapped/dax-tmp-2015-04-27_15_36_45-15805476788472573847-S09-1-81f2ef2477e4a2bc/NetworkActiveViews_232503_20150427* ?

Comment: No, the directory is empty.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for our debugging. This is a harmless error message and it should not impact your pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a harmless error message and it should not impact the pipeline.